# Can you use the Nintendo Switch Pro Controller with an Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, peripheral

I am wondering if the Nintendo Switch Pro Controller can be used with both the Nintendo Switch (obviously, it can) and my [appletv](/questions/tagged/appletv)(4th generation).

The specific controller I am referring to is this one:

[image: Nintendo Switch Pro Controller (front)]

I have looked online for the answer to my question, and the most information I could find relating to connecting Nintendo Switch’s official wireless controllers to an Apple device were articles such as [one from TechCrunch](https://www.techcrunch.com/2017/03/06/nintendo-switch-joy-con-and-pro-controllers-work-on-pc-mac-and-android/) and another from [AppleInsider](http://appleinsider.com/articles/17/03/06/how-to-play-mac-games-with-nintendo-switch-joy-con-and-pro-controllers/) on how to connect the Joy-Con controllers to a desktop or mobile Apple device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the article you linked to on AppleInsider, I noticed that it says that

> They will not work with iOS games, nor tvOS.

Since these controllers are not "Made for tvOS/iOS" certified, they will be unable to be used with your Apple TV. You will instead need to use a controller that *is* certified, like the [Horipad Ultimate](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HJ172ZM/A/horipad-ultimate-wireless-game-controller?fnode=aa) that is sold on the Apple Store.

You can find more compatible controllers that are sold on the Apple Store [here](https://www.apple.com/shop/tv/tv-accessories/remotes-controllers)

Comment: Well, that sucks.

Comment: To everyone arriving here via Google: Send Apple feedback with this link telling them you that you want to be able to use your existing console controllers with your Apple TV.

Feedback link: https://www.apple.com/feedback/appletv.html

Suggested Text: Please update the Apple TV software to allow pairing with Nintendo Switch / Sony Playstation / Microsoft XBOX bluetooth controllers. There is no reason to require your customers to buy another third party controller in order to play games on Apple TV when a lot of users already have a Bluetooth enabled controller.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming macOS Monterey has support for the Nintendo Pro and Joy-Cons.

The Apple engineer could not comment on future plans, so no info on support for the controllers on other platforms (tvOS, iOS and so on).

Answer (score 0):

This controler is usable also under tvOS and should work with iPadOS or iOS.
Simply just connect it via bluetooth.

See

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210414
- https://appleinsider.com/inside/ios-16/tips/how-to-use-nintendo-joy-cons-with-iphone-ipad-apple-tv